# Redirect a certain page on domain A to a certain page on domain B

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How would one redirect a certain page on domain A to a certain page on domain B in an htaccess file? We own both domains and both have nameservers pointing to a single server.

For example:

```
domainA.com/testpage
```

should go to

```
domainB.com/bestpageever
```

The following is as far as I have gotten. (I'm also forcing the www in front of the domain)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainA.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainB.com/bestpageever [R=301,L]
```

This happens to redirect all pages on domainA to the specified page on domainB, which is not what I want. No matter what kind of variation I try, I can't seem to get it to redirect just "testpage" on domainA to "bestpageever" on domainB.

Comment: What variations did you try? Have a look at [`RewriteRule`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_rewrite#rewriterule) docs.

Comment: not enough apparently...also, after seeing @arkascha 's answer, I think I may have misunderstood the docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is close to what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainA\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?testpage$ http://www.domainB.com/bestpageever [R=301]
```

The above rule will work in the http servers host configuration or in dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files).

If you place such rules in the http servers host configuration you can simplify those rules to this, since then the rules are only applied inside the specific http host they are configured in:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/testpage$ http://www.domainB.com/bestpageever [R=301]
```

A general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I'd probably keep those `RewriteCond`s because: "_We own both domains and both have nameservers pointing to a single server._" So unless you're sure that the DocRoot is different for both....

Comment: @hjpotter92 Indeed, thanks for pointing that out! Not necessarily an issue, but it might be one, depending on the setup.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Yes, the docroot is the same in our case. Unfortunately, I am dealing with a legacy system and they want to stay using the htaccess file method.